# Aws route S3 sub domain showing Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page even integrated the Virtual Host

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am facing issues with AWS EC2 and Route S3-hosted zone.
We have multiples application on a single EC2 instance and all are working under the folder name below:

```
Domain                     Folder  

www.example1.com           /var/www/html/example1.com
wwe.example2.com           /var/www/html/example2.com
www.example3.com           /var/www/html/example3.com
```

So now I want to create a sub-domain for [www.dev.example1.com](http://www.dev.example1.com) I have added the subdomain using route S3  hosted zone.
Create the dev.example1.com folder inside /var/www/html and also set the virtual host on Apache

**ISSUES**
Subdomain is working and showing me the default Apache page from the root it should pick the data from the  **/var/www/html/dev.example1.com**
[image]

Could anyone help with this?